# Countably infinite monoids with minimal right ideals

Tags: semigroups-and-monoids

Is there any classification of countably infinite monoids with minimal right ideal? or at least in some classes of monoids?

Comment: What would you hope to mean by a classifications?  You can take any countable monoid and adjoin a zero to get a minimal right ideal.

Comment: And all finite or compact monoids have minimal right ideals.

Comment: @Benjamin Steinberg Thanks for the guidance! For example, all commutative artinian monoids have this property. I want to know the other classes of monoids with this property and you kindly introduced me two new families.

Comment: Asking for classes with this property is more hopeful than asking for a classification.  Any monoid with descending chain condition on right ideals (e.g. finite monoids) has it, but there are many other ways to get them like artificially adding a 0.

Comment: @Benjamin Steinberg Thanks again, is there any reference about semigroups with descending chain condition on right ideals?

Comment: I think you can find some stuff on this in Clifford and Preston's classic book on semigroup theory.  They call it the minimum condition on right ideals.

Comment: @Benjamin Steinberg Thanks so much